# Как считать каждый символ в списке

Tags: python

У меня возникла проблема мне необходимо чтобы мой код подсчитать каждый элемент в списке.
Входные данные:

```
8
11
```

Выходные данные:
4 хотя он должен выводить 6

```py
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
e = list(range(a, b+1))
print(len(e))
```

Comment: А что означает `подсчитал каждый элемент` ??

Comment: Неправильно написал

Comment: ещё хуже стало. Откуда 6 должно взяться?

Comment: Смотри он считает все числа от 8 до 11 получается 8 9 10 11 и он должен подсчитать сколько всего символов. То есть 8 9 1 0 1 1 и получиться 6, но он считает 10 и 11 за 1 элемент

Comment: Входные данные 8, 11 это ДВА, а не четыре и не шесть!

Comment: print(sum([len(str(x)) for x in range(a, b+1)]))

Comment: @Эникейщик Картинка с орущими бабами и котом  19

Comment: `len(''.join(map(str, range(a, b + 1))))`

Comment: @MBo   . - . -

Comment: Да оно работает но с числами 1000000001 и 2000000000 не работает

Comment: @Sarevus А разве вы писали про такие диапазоны?

Comment: Ну не написал но думал то что оно будет и с такими диапазонами работать

Answer (score 4):

алгоритм:

- в цикле перебрать числа от `start` до `end`
- перевести число в строку
- на длину строки увеличить счётчик

метод работает в коротких диапазонах, если потребуется подсчитать кол-во символов от скажем 10^101 скажем до 10^1001, то такой метод работать уже не будет (слишком долго), тут потребуется уже чистая математика:

основной алгоритм:

- вычислить кол-во символов в диапазоне от `0` до `10^n` (`10^n ~ end`)
- вычислить кол-во символов в диапазоне от `0` до `10^m` (`10^m ~ start`)
- вычесть из первого второй :)

для таких вычислений надо:

- вычислить `l` - десятичный логарифм числа n, тем самым получив кол-во знаков у числа `n`
- дальше подсчитать по формуле

  ```
  s = sum(1, l - 1, i * 10^i) + (n - 10^l) * l
  ```

как-то примерно так